# MATLAB: Is it possible to get the joint state matrix from a cost function if I assume I know everything else? If so, am I doing it right?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, game-theory

So I am new in this field (game theory, optimal control) and trying to go a step forward on a project from this equation [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Gno.png)
which is the definition of joint cost function (I am dealing with 2 players), assuming for the second equality i know all variables except Q_alpha, the state x is a rectangular matrix, for initial time t=0 would this be the right way to solve for Q_alpha in matlab and to use the equation since in reality is an integral but i am assuming I want the value at initial time t=0?

Q_alpha= pinv(x')*(J_alpha - U' * M * U)*pinv(x)   %pinv or pseudoinverse since x is rectangular

(Maybe i am doing something not allowed but i am open to hear any advice, thanks a lot)

[Paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8913641&tag=1)

I expect the value of this matrix to be
Q_alpha = [1.1,0;0,1.1]

I get
Q_alpha =

```
  -1.0399     -0.41595
 -0.41595     -0.16638
```